# How to add a non-referenced image as overlay in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map, with tileLayer and markers. I would like to add an image overlay to add some effects and styling to the tiles.

L.imageOverlay is nice, but it requires bounds, whereas I would like to anchor the image to absolute pixels of the rendered map. For example to have an effect that is continuous towards the zoom levels.

It should be possible to do it by getting the extent and redefining the bounds of the layer each time, but it is ridiculous, as these would need to be converted to absolute values internally. Nevertheless, I couldn't find the way of doing it by reading the API.

You can image things like a frame, like fading, etc... on top of the map.

Comment: Do you really want to render this as a layer on the map? If you're looking to simply overlay an image, would you perhaps want to use an L.Control? Or, alternatively, if this is a static watermark or something, does it even need to be contained in the Leaflet container? Could you simply create an image and position it absolute in your markup?

Comment: Even through a L.control, I couldn't get how to have something always fixed to the window (full screen OK) and not to some bounds... L.control controls ILayers which "represents an object attached to a particular location". I would like to have it in the Leaflet container, because I would like to have this styling effect on the map, but not on the markers. And therefore as layer in between

Comment: So you are saying that a L.Control would work for you, if the positioning would always be fixed in an absolute position over the map, regardless of the bounds? L.Controls are anchored to the edges of the screen. For instance, if you were to create your own custom `position` anchor for an L.Control, you would be able to anchor it anywhere on the map using absolute positioning.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just tested this option, which is not bad except that it is still on top of everything. I was looking for an image overlay where the markers could still be on top of...

Comment: That is a tough problem. You might be able to play around with the `z-index` values but that might cause lots of unintended interactions.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but check out this plugin: https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Spin  It includes a spinner that is placed over the map, to indicate loading. It's somewhat relevant to what you are doing. Might be some tips in their source code for your case.

Comment: With the spin exemple, I see that it results in ending adding a layer, not anymore a control. There I can control the order, be under the markers, but I still don't know how to add a layer without bounds. And in the case that leaflet is done to have "under" the geo-referenced data and on top only the other elements, it may be hard to solve...

Comment: So if the spin demo is indeed adding a layer, this is good. Because as I pan the map around in their demo, the spinning logo does not move. This means it's a layer that is NOT geo-referenced. This is what you are aiming for, correct?

Comment: Yes, except I didn't get how to do it... I'm neither so familiar with these Map Mixins...

Comment: My only suggestion is to look at their code, see what they're doing specifically. Good luck to you, sir! See the API section on `includes` and `mixins` here: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#class

Answer (score 2):

You could use a control and a div to manipulate the image. Not sure if this helps.

```
var legend2 = L.control({position: 'topleft'}); 
legend2.onAdd = function (map) {        
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend2');
    div.innerHTML = '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" style="transform: matrix3d(-0.509677, 0.655299, 0, -0.000417152, 0.597349, 0.564009, 0, 0.000111701, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); ">';     
    return div;
};      
legend2.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks andrea! Unfortunately your response comes too late, this project isn't anymore active and I'm not able to test your proposition in order to accept your answer. But it may help some other people :-)

Answer (score 0):

Doing some reading as adding a watermark would be useful for us.  The intro for the core Spin.js library that leaflet.spin.js calls on mentions this:

> The spin() method creates the necessary HTML elements and starts the
>   animation. If a target element is passed as argument, the spinner is
>   added as first child and horizontally and vertically centered.

So when  `this._spinner = new Spinner().spin(this._container);` is called for the layer that is loading, the layer size is determined in pixels.  It's fixed in the DOM, not in the leaflet layers.

Comment: Nice other possibility ! Nevertheless, I think this layer is still above everything and not just on top of the tileLayers (and below markers), as is the overlay I was speaking about...